# How to save a jupyter notebook with outputs

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory

How can I save a jupyter notebook with outputs? I'm editing my notebook with Google Collab and want to save it as a .ipynb file with outputs shown, like here: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/krasserm/super-resolution/blob/master/example-srgan.ipynb.

But when I `Download .ipynb` on Google Collab, you can't see the outputs in the resulting file. How can I get the outputs to show?

Related question: how can I have the outputs save in the Google Collab doc? Right now, the outputs always disappear on reload, even though I disabled the hide outputs on save.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. When I downloaded it did show me the content. Make sure you used `Save` on the notebook before downloading (I uploaded my result to https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/ and it worked and showed the preview). If it doesn't work, check the next item on my list.
2. Double-check the settings at "Settings" -> "Site" and make sure "New notebooks use private outputs (omit outputs when saving)" is disabled. Similarly, check also "Edit" -> "Notebook settings" and make sure "Omit code cell output when saving this notebook" is disabled. Yes, **these are two separate settings**.
3. Retry 1# if it didn't work before after toggling both settings. Also, notebooks should now save the output.